# What term is used to describe a team chartered to solve a problem?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am struggling to recall a term that defines a team of people that is organized around a charter to solve a problem.

It's a term I've run across recently and I'm unable to recall it.  I'm hoping that others may be able to share suggestions.

Comment: In corporate jargon, a **tiger team**.

Comment: Thank you, Dan.  Looking for something more formal.  I modified the question to clarify the request.

Comment: Then maybe a **task force**?

Comment: Don't put *formal* in quotes if you're not going to provide more context. (Why do you have it in quotes? Are you insinuating something beyond its normal meaning?) *Tiger team* is perfectly formal in any business setting. Just because it's jargon, doesn't mean it's not formal for that setting.

Comment: Think tank, perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

You may be thinking of "blue ribbon panel".

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue-ribbon_panel

> In the United States, a blue-ribbon panel (or blue ribbon commission) is a group of exceptional people appointed to investigate, study or analyze a given question.

Comment: Not quite.  The group I'm thinking of must be formed around a defined charter. I'm sorry, but that's not it.  I appreciate the suggestion.  Got another perhaps?

Answer (score -2):

There's an appropriate term

***Ad-hocracy***

: a temporary organization or committee set up to accomplish a specific task
([MWD](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ad-hocracy))

According to [Collin's Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/adhocracy):

***adhocracy***

noun

management that  responds to urgent problems rather than planning to avoid them